# Materialized view refresh on create table

Tags: oracle11g

Is there a way to refresh a mview after the table that is used to build the mview is recreated?

Thanks,
Catalin.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "recreated"? Do you have a materialized view on a table T, then you drop T, then you re-create T (presumably including the columns that the view referenced, with the same names and data types as in the previous version of table T)?

In that case, use the `refresh` function in the `dbms_mview` package:

```
EXEC    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MVIEW_NAME')
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67203

Comment: I used another approach but DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MVIEW_NAME') works if the recreated table has the same data types and column names. Thanks!